# How can I add a FTP server as local folder?

Tags: windows, ftp

I want to add my FTP server as an local drive so that I can select it in Intellij. Currently I've added the FTP like an network drive in Windows but I can't see it when I click "Open new Project" in Intellij:

My Network Drive:

[image]

But not visible here:

[image]

I know that when I do this with a Mac I can mount it and it's visible because it's like a normal folder there. How can I do this in Windows?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a mounted volume but not at a drive letter.  It seems that MS's directions are out of date for Win10

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking-winpc/map-ftp-directory-as-a-drive/fb6825ec-8ec8-484d-8298-139bcaef567f

but it looks like FTPUSE will work for you

https://www.ferrobackup.com/map-ftp-as-disk.html

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll try this out now and let you know if it worked